# Help with Linq expression to return a list of strings based on field count

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Say I have a table Comments with these columns: Id, Comment, Category, CreatedDate, CommenterId

I want to get the top 5 categories from the Comments table (based on the count of each category in that table).  How can I do this in linq, to return either List or IQueryable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var topComments = from comment in Comments
                  group comment by comment.Category into grp
                  orderby grp.Count() descending
                  select grp.Key;

var topFive = topComments.Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks @scmccart and @Mark Byers.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this:

```
var query = comments
    .GroupBy(comment => comment.Category)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .Take(5);
```